# Woocommerce checkout page reload on up dating shipping method

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, jquery

I got 3 shipping method
free
local pick up
flat rate

I got a small jquery function to determind when ever i should show/hide free shipping method, it works but, when i get to the checkout page i have everyhing hidden regarding shipping method, user selects an option and based on that it will display all or few shipping method, when the option "non free" is selected from a checkbox it hides the free shipping and show the rest, but when user select flat rate or pick up method something seems to reload and basically remove my script and let free shipping vissible

```
<script>
      $(".checkboxClass").change(function(){
if (selectedName == "nonFree") {
 
    $(" #shipping_method_0_free_shipping7").parent().hide(); 
  $(" #shipping_method_0_free_shipping7").parent().addClass("hideMe");
    }
  else 
    {
      $(" #shipping_method_0_free_shipping7").parent().show(); 
       $(" #shipping_method_0_free_shipping7").parent().removeClass("hideMe");
       
      
    }
  });
  </script>
```